# How can I use JS to fill out a simple input field when the ".value = ***" doesnt seem to be recognized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

Every day I have a "health and fitness" steps tracker that needs to be entered at work. I am trying to use TamperMonkey to automate most of it. However, I am having trouble getting the input field to validate my "value".

[image]

I execute the console command:

```
document.getElementById("self-enter-steps-input").value = 3000;
```

which yields:

[image]

However, when I hit "Save" manually, I get the following error:

[image]

If I hit "Save" programmatically, the window closes but the number doesnt register. If I hit "backspace" or type an extra "0" manually, the entire field gets validated and it saves the whole value if I hit submit.

I've also tried entering the value as a string i.e.

```
document.getElementById("self-enter-steps-input").value = "3000";
```

The field gets validated but the value doesn't get recorded. A simple backspace or extra number typed manually does, however, make the entire field record.

I've tried some simulated "keypress" events with no success. Im a JS newbie so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked that the ID is correct? JS is case sensitive

Comment: @SathishChelladurai Why else would you see "3000" in the input field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to trigger a change listener manually by dispatching a `change` event manually:

```
const steps = document.getElementById("self-enter-steps-input");
steps.value = "3000";
const change = new InputEvent('change', { bubbles: true });
steps.dispatchEvent(change);
```

By the looks of it the validation of the input happens on either `change`, `blur` (or alternatively `focusout` because `blur` won't bubble), or `input`. Please check your developer tools for which event is actually being listened, and adjust the code I gave accordingly.

Comment: Both answers were correct, I needed to dispatch the "change" event.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe field is validated on specific event, for example `change`. Try to trigger it after setting value

```
var inputElement = document.getElementById("self-enter-steps-input");
var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');

inputElement.value = 3000;

e.initEvent('change', false, true);
inputElement.dispatchEvent(e);
```